# Error msg: ;; Warning: Message parser reports malformed message packet

Tags: networking, macos, google-chrome, dns

It started a few weeks ago and it's intermittent. Going to google.com,Facebook.com would return

```
This site can’t be reached
www.google.com’s server IP address could not be found.
```

This happens even if I was on the site earlier in the day. Sometimes booting the router or laptop would resolve the issue but not always. Sometimes It would start working after being left alone overnight.

Doing a nslookup or dig returns:

```
jeffreyschwartz@jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:/usr/bin$ nslookup google.com
;; Warning: Message parser reports malformed message packet.
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: \# 4 ACD907AE
jeffreyschwartz@jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:/usr/bin$ dig google.com
;; Warning: Message parser reports malformed message packet.
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29237
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: Message has 26875 extra bytes at end
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     30825   RESERVED0 A \# 4 ACD907AE
;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 13 18:53:28 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 26929
```

Clearing the cache `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;` says `cache flushed` didn't help.

Some other commands that I found that might be useful.

```
scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fios-router.home
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[2] : 192.168.1.1
  nameserver[3] : 1.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fios-router.home
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[2] : 192.168.1.1
  nameserver[3] : 1.0.0.1
  if_index : 5 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
jeffreyschwartz@jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:/usr/bin$

jeffreyschwartz@jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:/usr/bin$ dns-sd -G v4 google.com
DATE: ---Mon 13 Apr 2020---
19:01:39.457  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags if Hostname                               Address                                      TTL
19:01:40.531  Add        2  0 google.com.                            0.0.0.0                                      77   No Such Record
^C
jeffreyschwartz@jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:/usr/bin$ dns-sd -V
Currently running daemon (system service) is version 880.70.3

dscacheutil -q host -a name google.com
name: google.com
ipv6_address: 2607:f8b0:4004:800::200e
```

The issue happens in safari, google chrome, and Brave. macOS is Mojave v10.14.6 (18G4032). All other software are up do date.

I can also provide a wireshark or other info as needed.