# Unable to find proxy with Windscribe add-on

Tags: firefox, vpn, firefox-extensions

I've been having [some trouble with my Internet connection for a few weeks now](https://superuser.com/questions/1541664/error-msg-warning-message-parser-reports-malformed-message-packet/1545870#1545870), and I'm linking a reference because it may be related.

In spite of having that sort of problem, I could connect to some sites without much trouble, especially when I use TorBrowser. But this one has not only some restrictions by itself to make navigation private but also some site's restrictions against it.

I'm using mainly two other web browsers: Brave-browser 1.5.115 (based on Chromium) and Firefox 76.0.1. I've got Windscribe addon installed on both browsers (version 3.1.6 on Firefox and 3.1.7 on Brave).

I can use this extension on Brave without any problem, but when it comes to surf on the Internet with Firefox and this VPN add-on I just cannot. No matter the country I select (I've got a free account and it provides a lot of countries and I didn't run out of data, so this isn't the problem) it just keeps giving me the "Unable to find the proxy server" error message.

I do not have any proxy server configured under the Firefox preferences, and this is not the problem as it used to work fine this way. And I'm sure it's still not the problem because I accepted a Firefox's update two days ago and it was working again (it didn't work properly for quite a few weeks). I was using it, and suddenly I couldn't connect to a page and then realised I couldn't connect to any other webpage.

There's also the Windscribe desktop application, this way any traffic would use the VPNs, not only the web browser's. But I stopped using it because TorBrowser would lost connection.

No matter I can use other web browsers, I want to work with Firefox as well, since Brave is more restrictive than Firefox, but less than TorBrowser, and there are some pages I cannot connect with any of them but Firefox.

If you wonder whether or not I can work with Firefox without being "connected" to the VPNs, the answer is I do, but I'd like to solve this problem and to work the way I want to. They are designed to work properly, and I'm not sure what is going on.

I love learning about how network works, and I can solve some sort of problems as I have studied some network administration. But I failed to grasp what may go wrong here.

Any tip?

Thank you!

P.D.: To make things weirder, I'm running into the same problem with Brave, I've noticed when I tried to submit this message. I've tried to open a new page and I couldn't, I'v tried to connect to another available country and still have the same reply from the browser, I can connect to the Internet if I turn off the VPNs connection. Is somebody blocking these VPNs' connections? How to figure out and solve it?

Comment: I use both the Windscribe app in Windows and, on occasion, the add-on in Firefox, and I've never encountered any such problem. You should uninstall the add-on on all your browsers, restart them after clearing all personal data, and install it again, or switch to the desktop app, just to check if it works that way. I too am on the free tier (color me cheap), and though it's sometimes a bit slow depending on the server you connect to, it usually does the job pretty well. Say what you want about the Canadians, but they deliver... :-)

Comment: Some more wierd things have happened. I got the unable to connect without the VPN activated and I could browse with the VPN add-on running. In the end, I decided to try again the desktop version, and it could work along with TorBrowser, I think I used to activate the VPN while TorBrowser running.
Everything worked fine for today, it's not the final solution because of the bandwidth.
On the other hand, at least I installed and deployed successfully a DNS over TLS like stubby (I use GNU/Linux).
I don't think there will be more answers and I couldn't see how to make your answer the good one.

Comment: As long as it works out for you, I'm good.